# Soma de profiles no maven?

Tags: maven

Cenário:

Tenho 10 clientes, 3 deles usam websphere , 10 usam tomcat, 7 usam jboss.
no `pom.xml`

```
<profile>
    <id>cliente01</id>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- depencias para tomcat-->
    </dependencies>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>cliente02</id>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- depencias para tomcat-->
    </dependencies>
</profile>  
<profile>
    <id>cliente03</id>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- depencias para tomcat-->
    </dependencies>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>cliente04</id>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- depencias para jboss-->
    </dependencies>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>cliente04</id>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- depencias para jboss-->
    </dependencies>
</profile>      

...
```

Dessa maneira funciona, mas para todos clientes que usam `tomcat` as dependecias ficam se repetindo (o mesmo para jboss e websphere).

**Existem uma maneira mais eficiente de fazer isso?**

Eu estava esperando algo do tipo:

```
<profile>
    <id>jboss</id>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- depencias para jboss-->
    </dependencies>
</profile>
<profile>
    <id>tomcat</id>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- depencias para tomcat-->
    </dependencies>
</profile>  
<profile>
    <id>websphere</id>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- depencias para websphere-->
    </dependencies>
</profile>


<profile>
    <id>cliente01</id>
    <useProfile>jboss</useProfile>
</profile>


<profile>
    <id>cliente02</id>
    <useProfile>tomcat</useProfile>
</profile>      

...
```

Comment: Porque você não coloca as libs que são especificas de cada servidor na pasta de libs de cada servidor.. e deixa apenas as libs que a aplicação usa no pom do projeto? assim você não teria mais libs repetidas..

Comment: Não daria certo. Eu crio um .war e entrego para o cliente. O proprio cliente é quem gerencia o servidor, eu somente entrego aplicação.